# React-router 4 -- NavLink with shared component not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

When using React-Router 4, certain programmatically-generated NavLinks aren't being marked as active consistently.  I have a sidebar in my react frontend that looks something like this:

```
<NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/books">Books</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/poems">Poems</NavLink>
{['hamlet', 'macbeth'].map(play => (
    <NavLink to={`/plays/${play}` key={`play-${play}`}}>{play}</NavLink>
)}}
```

And my routing looks something like this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={HomePageComponent} exact />
    <Route path="/books" component={BooksComponent} />
    <Route path="/poems" component={PoemsComponent} />
    <Route path="/plays/:title" component={PlayComponent} />
    <Route path="/plays/:title/:act" component={ActComponent} />
</Switch>
```

When I navigate between **to** one of the the play links, say from `/books` to `/plays/macbeth`, the NavLink updates the tab appropriately.  When I navigate **between** the plays, say from `/plays/macbeth` to `/plays/hamlet`, the NavLink doesn't update and the original tab (in this case, Macbeth) remains active.

I suspect the problem is that because the component is not changing, something in the NavLink isActive check isn't firing.  This is further confirmed by the fact that if I navigate to a different sub-link -- say, `/plays/hamlet/actI`, and then to `/plays/macbeth`, the Macbeth tab is marked as active as expected.  So, is there a way to force the `NavLink` to update even if the Component hasn't changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `exact` prop:

```
<Route exact path="/plays/:title" component={PlayComponent} />
```

Doc: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool

**UPDATE**:
Since you think it's not re-rendering because it's the same component, also try this:

```
<Route path="/plays/:title" component={(props) => (<PlayComponent {...props}/>) } />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: I tried that and should probably update my question to reflect that.  Not only did it not solve the problem, it actually made the problem worse, since the subsections (like `/plays/hamlet/actI`) __stopped__ being marked as active on the sidebar, which is not the intended outcome.

Comment: the updated suggestion fixed it, thanks.  It seemed to force a re-render even if the component didn't change, which fixed the NavLink problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced such a problem too. And I have tried those two solutions mentioned above, but failed.
In my application, there is a `<App>` component and it does:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/list/:type" component={List} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and `<List>` renders `<Header />`, `<Header />` renders `<Category />`, `<Category />` renders a series of `<NavLink />`, which is like

```
<NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink>
<NavLink exact to="/list/abc">ABC</NavLink>
<NavLink exact to="/list/efg">EFG</NavLink>
```

If I switch from Home to ABC then the result meets my expectation: classname `active` will be set on `ABC`. However, if I switch from ABC to EFG, things become terrible, only `ABC` owns classname `active`.

This problem troubles me a lot, wish to gain your answers. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are using React.component and not React.PureComponent